# How to adjust tableofcontents?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, numbering

How Can I adjust \tableofcontents in this way ?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,x11names]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage
Here stars the document... after the index\\
\part{Part I One}
\blindtext
\section{Section A of I}
\blindtext
\subsection{Subesction Jei}
\blindtext
\subsection{Subesction Jeii}
\blindtext
\section{Section B of I}
\blindtext
\subsection{Subesction Jeiii}
\blindtext
\subsection{Subesction Jeiiiii}
\blindtext
\section{Section C of I}
\blindtext
\subsection{Subesction Jeei}
\blindtext
\subsection{Subesction Jeeei}
\blindtext
\part{Part II Two}
\blindtext
\subsection{Subesction Jeeeei}
\blindtext
\section{Section A of II}
\blindtext
\subsection{Subesction Jerr}
\blindtext
\subsection{Subesction Jeddd}
\blindtext
\section{Section B of II}
\blindtext
\subsection{Subesction Jesss}
\part{Part III Three}
\blindtext
\section{Section A of III}
\subsection{Subesction Jerr}
\section{Section B of III}
\blindtext
\subsection{Subesction Jer}
\part{Part IV Four}
\section{Section A of IV}
\blindtext
\subsection{Subesction Jeittiii}
\blindtext\subsection{Subesction Jeiit}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\usepackage{chngcntr}\counterwithin{section}{part}`.

Comment: \gonzalo-medina It doesn´t work well . Number over numbers !! http://sensa.square7.ch/gfgfd54.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{section}{part}
```

Since using Roman numerals for parts leaves now little space between the number and the title for section and subsection entris, some additional adjustment is needed, which can be easily done using the `tocloft` package (adjust the lengths according to your needs):

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\cftsetindents{section}{0em}{2.5em}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{2.5em}{3.5em}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,x11names]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{section}{part}

\cftsetindents{section}{0em}{2.5em}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{2.5em}{3.5em}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage
Here stars the document... after the index\\
\part{Part I One}

\section{Section A of I}

\subsection{Subesction Jei}

\subsection{Subesction Jeii}

\section{Section B of I}

\subsection{Subesction Jeiii}

\subsection{Subesction Jeiiiii}

\section{Section C of I}

\subsection{Subesction Jeei}

\subsection{Subesction Jeeei}

\part{Part II Two}

\subsection{Subesction Jeeeei}

\section{Section A of II}

\subsection{Subesction Jerr}

\subsection{Subesction Jeddd}

\section{Section B of II}

\subsection{Subesction Jesss}
\part{Part III Three}

\section{Section A of III}
\subsection{Subesction Jerr}
\section{Section B of III}

\subsection{Subesction Jer}
\part{Part IV Four}
\section{Section A of IV}

\subsection{Subesction Jeittiii}
\subsection{Subesction Jeiit}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Gracias (Thank you), and for substitute the roman numbers for  1,2,3....  ?

Comment: @MikaIke De nada. `\renewcommand\thepart{\arabic{part}}`.

Comment: Gracias (Thank you), I compile twice and have regular results, but TOC point Part D to page 10, and in the reality Part D is in page 11. Is this normal?

Comment: @MikaIke No, this is not normal. At this point, I'd suggest you to open a fresh new question and to provide there a minimal complete document illustrating the problem, so we can diagnose the problem and propose solutions.